# File Upload in static/css/question_image folder

Tags: java, spring

I want to upload a file in static/css/question_image which is a directory in my Spring Boot project.

By using below code i am able to upload the image but it is getting stored in my local system some directory and it doesn't appear in project folder structure.

```
            Iterator<String> itr =multipartHttpServletRequest.getFileNames();

                 while(itr.hasNext()){
                     fileName = itr.next();
                     MultipartFile file =multipartHttpServletRequest.getFile(fileName);
                     System.out.println("File name is "+file.getOriginalFilename());
                     byte[] byteArr = file.getBytes();
                     File convFile = new File("static/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
                     convFile.createNewFile();   
                     BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(convFile);

                     stream.write(byteArr);
                     stream.close();
```

Comment: When you do this kind of operation. use `try` and `catch` that would help you to debug the code.

Comment: yes it is there i am not getting any exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your file is in the "static" sub-directory of the current directory, which, possibly, is the directory containing your JAR. You can't write back into the "project folder structure", as that appears to be in the JAR.

I suggest you rethink what you are intending to do with the output and where it needs to go.

Comment: I want to upload an image into a folder called question_image which is in static/css/question_image